# Weird spacing of numbers with siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx

When I use `\num{2.17989e-2}`, I get the following output:

[image]

As you can see, there is a weird space between 9 and 8 in the decimals. Why is this happening and how can I eliminate it?

Comment: looks like a thin space every three digits siunitx has setup options to control that

Comment: It is possible the spacing is from rendering resolution (i.e., not in the underlying PDF, but in the way, for example, Adobe renders it at a given resolution).  Without a small code of yours to test, one cannot say.  Please edit your question and provide a minimum working example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for `siunitx` manual:

> Grouping digits into blocks of three is a common method to increase the ease of reading of numbers.

So the default behavior of the package is precisely that, to group the digits. But there is an option to activate/deactivate that (as David said in his comment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {siunitx} % I have version 2020/02/25

\sisetup{group-digits=false} % changes the defalut (true)


\begin{document}
Ungrouped digits (default now): \num{2.17989e-2}.

\bigskip

Grouped digits: \num[group-digits=true]{2.17989e-2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]